# How to upload file using LrHttp.posMultipart in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I need to send the image file using multipart request from Lightroom to my local web service using Lua language.

I have tested using sending headers also but not working...

I have created a function :

```
function testupload(filepath) --created inside LrTasks

local url = "http://localhosturl"
local mycontent = {
            {
                name = "lightroom_message",
                value = "sent from lightroom plugin multiparta"
            },


    {
                    name = 'file',
                    filePath = filepath,
                    fileName = LrPathUtils.leafName(filepath),
                    contentType = 'image/jpeg'
                    --contentType = 'multipart/form-data'
                }
        }

 local response, headers = LrHttp.postMultipart(url, mycontent)
```

end

But my web service  is not getting called properly and I am using LrHttp.postMultipart() method to do so..

If I am sending just  this param to web service (then working fine):

```
{
     name = "lightroom_message",
     value = "sent from lightroom plugin multiparta"
}
```

but when I include my file payload then its not working using pure Lua implementation.

Comment: this is not valid Lua code. try `function testupload() .... end` instead of `function testupload(){ ... }`

Comment: @moteus I know and I have edited it....but just want to know why postMultipart not working .....and what is wrong in my table (mycontent) which is the body of my post request

Comment: what do you mean by "no called properly"
and where did you define filepath?

Comment: @Piglet I am passing the path of file in the function testupload

Answer (score 0):

Everything was correct but just a technical mistake...I was trying to call the testupload() function from inside LRtasks..but we dont need to call it in separate task and the function works perfect